# Windows Shutdown Times (hour-minute), how can I know - Is there any small batch file or something similiar for this?

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch, shutdown

I used to learn the Windows Shutdown times from event viewer - however in windows 8.1 as you may be aware there is no full shutdown. So I can not view the system shutdown time. But I do not want to disable quickboot only for this purpose, since it is convenient.

Is there any simple command line or something similar that will write to a log file system shutdown times, hour minute etc., so I can view later when the system was shut down? The last 10 shutdowns, in example.

I believe there are many shutdown timers out there, but these software are bulky for simply viewing the shutdown time - they also have other purposes.

Any simple script or something like this? As a last resort, I can use a windows shutdown timer etc. if they view the last time I shutdown. Any suggestions?

Edit: For the poster below, as I mentioned, I always want hybrid (quick boot). So I would like to learn if there is another way to learn shutdown time by simply using a batch command or a software. If I disable quickboot, then it will not be convenient.

Comment: "in windows 8.1 as you may be aware there is no full shutdown" - Yes, there is, you just have to disable hybrid shutdown ( by turning off fast start up ) or issue the correct command instead ( `shutdown /f /s /t 0` ).  The time is only going to be updated when you do a full boot.

Comment: Sorry - No. As I told in the first post, I know how to disable it. I just want to know how I can do it without disabling it.

Comment: What do you mean by "learn shutdown time".

Comment: I mean that - I would like to know when the windows was last shutdown. In example, last night when did I shut down the computer. Just hour and minute. A simple batch file would be OK, showing the hour and minute of last 5 shutdown. I mean just like this one - http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/160855-shut-down-view-details-last-shutdown-computer.html   However this no longer works because of fast boot. And I do not want to disable fast boot just for this purpose.

Comment: If you don't want to disable fast boot then you won't be able to keep track of this information.

Comment: Any other way? such as a program running in the background, and when windows is shutdown I see the shutdown from its logs? I mean a program tracking its own shutdown time will already show this log, it being shutdown when windows is shutdown.